# Best way to organise the Java jars

Tags: java, rtc

We have 2 Java projects both have RTC(IBM Rational Team Concert) Java Plain Libraries( Used for interacting to RTC components programmatically).

So for any new tool we will build we need these libraries which amounts 30 mb.

Is there any best to organise this?

Comment: Still the best way would seem to use the **maven** build infrastructure. A search for both will find some plugins, and other guide lines.

Comment: @chandra and why that size matters?

Comment: Just consider we have project A with libs and proj B with libs (note: libs used projs are same) and when I add proj a as dependency to Proj B, when I export a jar with libs in different folder then I see each jar getting duplicated and I have to manually remove them.

Answer (score 1):

> we need these libraries which amounts 30 mb.

If by 30mb you refer to the library binaries (ie binary dependencies), then RTC (an ALM - Application Lifecycle Management - dealing wiht tickets, source control and task scheduling) is not involved.
You need to store those binaries in an [artifact repository like Nexus](https://www.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-oss), and declare those dependencies in a `pom.xml` present in each of your other RTC components.

If you wanted to keep a source dependencies, then you would make sure those two libraries sources are in their own components, and you would add said component on your projects stream. That is not the best practice for Java projects though.

In both approaches, the libraries are each in their own component, which allows them to evolve at their own pace, with their own baselines.

Comment: Yes I agree for dependencies but how to handle below situation, Just consider we have project A with libs and proj B with libs (note: libs used projs are same) and when I add proj a as dependency to Proj B, when I export a jar with libs in different folder then I see each jar getting duplicated and I have to manually remove them.

Comment: @chandrasekhar duplication is not an issue, each project is able to build itself, with its own libraries (even if they are the same). The important point is that those libraries are not stored in RTC, but in a separate referential (dedicated to store binaries)